# Splitting a ruby class into multiple files

Tags: ruby, file, class

I've discovered that I can split a class into multiple files by calling `class <sameclassname>; <code> ;end` from within each file. I've decided to divide up a very large class this way. The advantages I see:

- I can have separate spec files called by guard to reduce spec time.
- Forces me to organize and compartmentalize my code

Are there any pitfalls to this method? I can't find any information about people doing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I often do this in my gem files to manage documentation and avoid long files.

The only issues I found (which are solvable) are:

1. Initialization of class or module data should be thoughtfully managed. As each 'compartment' (file) is updated, the initialization data might need updating, but that data is often in a different file and we are (after all) fallible.

   In my GReactor project (edit: deprecated), I wrote a different initialization method for each section and called all of them in the main initialization method.
2. Since each 'compartment' of the class or module is in a different file, it is easy to forget that they all share the same namespace, so more care should be taken when naming variables and methods.
3. The code in each file is executed in the order of the files being loaded (much like it would be if you were writing one long file)... but since you 'close' the class/module between each file, than your method declaration order might be important. Care should be taken when requiring the files, so that the desired order of the code execution is preserved.

The GReactor is a good example for managing a Mega-Module with a large API by compartmentalizing the different aspects of the module in different files.

There are no other pitfalls or issues that I have experienced.

Answer (score 3):

Defining / reopening the same class in many different files makes it harder to locate the source of any given method, since there's no one clear place for it.

This also opens up the possibility of nasty loading sequence bugs, eg. file A is trying to call a method in file B, but file B has not loaded yet.

Having a very large class is a sign that the class is trying to do too much, and should be split up into smaller modules/subclasses. Sandi Metz's [POODR](http://presentboldly.com/brianllamar/poodr/11) recommends limiting classes to under 100 lines, among other guidelines.

Comment: POODR link is broken, don't happen to have a new link per chance?

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby classes are never closed. What you call "splitting" is actually just reopening the class. You can reopen classes and add methods to them at any time. If you define a class in file `A` and include it in file `B`, even if you reopen the class in file `B` it'll still contain all the code from file `A`. I personally prefer only to reopen a class when I have to. It sounds like in your case, I would define my class in one file. I think this method is better organized and has a lower risk of interfering with previously defined methods. More on the subject at [rubylearning](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_open_classes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good collection of Ruby design patters, or actually design pattern examples in Ruby: https://github.com/nslocum/design-patterns-in-ruby

Take a look at `decorator` as a good way to achieve modularity without a rigid parent<->child tree of classes.

Answer (score 0):

The only pitfall is that your class is split in multiple files, that you need to menage. User of your class would only need to require the second file, so if your class is part of gem or some package, they probably wouldn't even be aware that it was ever reopened.